# Bash script to compile a program, feed it with 15 input files and print stdout to file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to write a Bash script that feeds my program (./program) with 15 input files named in sequence as (file01.txt, file02.txt, etc) and print the outputs to the file (result.out). Here is the code I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Compile the current version

g++ -std=c++11 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage program.cpp -o program
#
#Output file
outFile=result.out

#Loop through files and print output
for i in *.txt; do
    ./program < $i > $outFile
done
```

I'm getting a segmentation fault when running this script and not sure what I did wrong. This is my first time to write a bash script, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, most likely you have a problem in `program`, but we clearly can't tell you what that problem is because we can't see the source for `program.cpp`. Fire up your favorite debugger and step through the code of that program and see what's causing the issue. The only thing in your bash script that would cause the error would be within `./program`, and you're the only one who can debug it with whatever input you're providing to it.

Comment: Why not quote `"$i"` to protect against filenames with spaces. If you have some and fail to adequately validate your opening of the file, an unquoted `$i` will most likely cause a segfault when you attempt to read from an invalid file stream resulting from the attempt to open a file based on 1/2 a filename....

Comment: Alright, I got the point that the segmentation fault is from my program. Thanks. Now I need the output file to contain 15 outputs from the 15 text files; However, I'm getting just one output. Any ideas?

Comment: You are always naming your output file the same (result.out). How can you expect different outputs?

Comment: Try `./program < “$i” > “result-${i}.out”`

Comment: Append the output. Use `>>` instead of `>`

Comment: I got this done. Thanks Ken, David, user1934428, Mark and mathB

Answer (score 0):

Basically these are the points I learnt from my conversation with stackoverflow members:

1- The segmentation fault is not related to bash script. It is definitely related to the program the bash command is running.

2- The bash script that feeds a program with text files and insert the results in an output file is as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Compile the current version
g++ -std=c++11 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage program.cpp -o program
#
#Test output file
outFile=results.out
# print "Results" into outFile
printf "Results\n" > $outFile
# loops through text files, send files to stdin 
# and insert stdout to outFile
for i in *.txt; do
    printf "\n$i\n" 
    ./program < "$i" 
done >> $outFile
```

Comment: You can remove `# Clear outfile` and `printf “” > $outFile` if you change `printf “Results\n” >> $outFile` to `printf “Results\n” > $outFile`

Comment: You can remove `>> $outFile` on second to last and third to last line and just change last line to `done >> $outFile`

Comment: Mark, I really like your changes. Thanks a lot

Comment: Although it doesn’t matter in this particular instance, technically you should put both `>> $outFile` in double quotes, thus `>> ”$outFile”`. As it stands, your script would fail if your output file had a space in its name.